# How use PyCuda in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, cuda, multiprocessing, pycuda

the problem is not to use CUDA in processes, but that if the parent already has an initialized CUDA, then in processes can not initialize it. If you just make the initialization in the parent and throw it into the processes, but it does not work. Here is an example just in the processes:

```
from pyfft.cuda import Plan
import numpy
import pycuda.driver as cuda
from pycuda.tools import make_default_context
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray

from multiprocessing import Process

def do_this_fft(data):
    cuda.init()
    context = make_default_context()
    stream = cuda.Stream()
    plan = Plan((16, 16), stream=stream)

    gpu_data = gpuarray.to_gpu(data)
    plan.execute(gpu_data)
    result = gpu_data.get()
    del gpu_data
    print(result)
    context.pop()
    del plan,stream,context

data = numpy.ones((16, 16), dtype=numpy.complex64)
process_list=[Process(target=do_this_fft,args=(data,)).start() for i in range(2)]
```

But if we write code like this, then nothing will work anymore

```
from pyfft.cuda import Plan
import numpy
import pycuda.driver as cuda
from pycuda.tools import make_default_context
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray

from multiprocessing import Process

def start_cuda_and_fft(data):
    cuda.init()
    context = make_default_context()
    stream = cuda.Stream()
    plan = Plan((16,16), stream=stream)
    context.pop()
    del plan,stream,context
    process_list=[Process(target=do_this_fft,args=(data,plan)).start() for i in range(2)] 

def do_this_fft(data):
    cuda.init() #<---------------Error
    '''
    File "test.py", line 35, in do_this_fft
        cuda.init()
    LogicError: cuInit failed: initialization error

    '''
    context = make_default_context()
    stream = cuda.Stream()
    plan = Plan((16, 16), stream=stream)

    gpu_data = gpuarray.to_gpu(data)
    plan.execute(gpu_data)
    result = gpu_data.get()
    context.pop()
    del plan,stream,context
    print(result)

data = numpy.ones((16, 16), dtype=numpy.complex64)
process_list=[Process(target=do_this_fft,args=(data,)).start() for i in range(2)]
```

The error is the following:

> File "test.py", line 35, in do_this_fft cuda.init() LogicError: cuInit failed: initialization error

I have already tried to do the context, the plan and push into the process, all without consequences.

Comment: What do you mean: "...then nothing will work anymore". Can you be more specific?

Comment: In the current example 
    File "test.py", line 35, in do_this_fft
         cuda.init()
    LogicError: cuInit failed: initialization error

Comment: When you want to do multiprocessing from a single parent process, don't initialize CUDA in the parent process. Initialize it in the child processes only, and do your work there.  So get rid of all the CUDA activity in `start_cuda_and_fft`

Comment: Yes, it's logical, but the example above is exaggerated from a real project, there it is necessary to have a CUDA in the parent process. Perhaps we can de-initialize CUDA, but I don't know how?

Comment: It simply won't work.  You cannot initialize CUDA in a parent process and expect it to work properly in a child process spawned from that parent process.  Study [this sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simpleipc) carefully.  I'm reasonably confident that it would not be necessary to initialize CUDA in your parent process, with some restructuring of your code.  The sample code demonstrates one possible approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't initialize CUDA before fork() so we need to spawn a new process

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and solve it by adding a line of code on the main process, before start the subprocesses:

```
 multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
```

Source: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/55812288/8664574]